# Problems in running java on mac

Tags: java, macos, user-interface, classpath

I am using a Macbook Pro, Maverics OS, 64 bit machine.
Actually I am facing a very itchy problem while running java programs on my computer.

For example, this is my code:

```
package com.gui.helloworld;



import javax.swing.JOptionPane;



/**
 * <p>Hello World popup</p>
 * This class simply pops up a "Hello, World!"
 * message graphically.
 *
 * @author Aditya R.Singh
 * @version 1.0
 * @since 2014-06-22
 */
public class GUIHelloWorld {

    /**
     * This is the method that will popup the 
     * "Hello, World!" message.
     * @param args Unused
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

When I compile my code like this,

```
javac com/gui/helloworld/GUIHelloWorld.java
```

a GUIHelloWorld.class is produced.
Upto this place, it is fine.

**BUT THE PROBLEM ARISES HERE**

When I try to run the code like this:

```
java com.gui.helloworld.GUIHelloWorld
```

It gives me an error like

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.gui.helloworld.GUIHelloWorld
```

So I have to compile the program like this:

```
java -classpath . com.gui.helloworld.GUIHelloWorld
```

Now, the output appears.
That's fine, but still, why is the need to put that "classpath" when the .class file is in
the same directory?
I am not liking this style.
This wasn't a problem when I used to use a windows 7 machine two months ago.
Any help? Or is it so that it is necessary for mac OS?
Please help.

Thanks, in advance ;)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis M sorry, I edited the question. Please read it again and help me. Actually I used the fully qualified package name. I just forgot to put it up here. M sorry

Comment: Also, setting `-classpath` to `.` is the default. Please give more details about how you run `java`. What is your current working directory? What are in the corresponding folders?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis name of my directory is "JavaHelloWorld". I have a package "com/gui/helloworld" in the directory "JavaHelloWorld". I have GUIHelloWorld.java in "com/gui/helloworld". After compilation, I have GUIHelloWorld.class and GUIHelloWorld.java both in "com/gui/helloworld". And my terminal was and is currently opened in "JavaHelloWorld" directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javac or java without a classpath option have the working directory as the default classpath.

References to classes must include package names. So if you compile and execute

```
javac One.java
java One
```

class One should be in the default package (no package statement). If you compile

```
javac a/b/Two.java
```

class Two should be in the package a.b. Then, execution of the .class file a/b/Two.class is possible using

```
java a.b.Two
```

Other "effects" are possible by setting the environment variable CLASSPATH, which can be overridden by the `-cp` option. (Possibly this is what happened in your case - check by running `echo $CLASSPATH`.)

Comment: Hey, this `$CLASSPATH` environment variable. Is it because I have set a `$CLASSPATH` environment variable to something else??? Is it so that I have to put the `classpath` while running???

Comment: Well, is it set? What do you get from that `echo $CLASSPATH`? If it *is* set, and does not contain '.', then you must use `-classpath .`

Comment: I did set it to my `$JAVA_HOME/bin`

Comment: This setting is pointless. You can (and should) add this directory to your PATH, but unset CLASSPATH.